# How to calculate the age of a person using variables like: year, month, day in PHP

Tags: php, html, if-statement, variables, operators

I have tried to get the age of a person, using the code below, although I wanted the output to be your exact age, it reads an incorrect age if your birthday was before the current date but a correct age if your birthday is after the current date kindly correct the code

```
<?php
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $month = $_POST['month']; 
   $day = $_POST['day'];  
   $year = $_POST['year'];
   $age = date('Y') - $year - 1 ;
   if (date('F') <= $month) {
        $age = date('Y') - $year;
   } 
   $nos = $_POST['nos'];
   $gender = $_POST['gender'];
   $loa = $_POST['loa'];

   echo "<div style ='font:21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#7a1ac4'><b>`Name:`</b> $name</div>";
   echo "<div style ='font:21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#7a1ac4'><b>`Birth Date:`</b> 
   $month-$day-$year </div>";
   echo "<div style ='font:21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#7a1ac4'><b>`Age:`</b> aprox. 
   $age</div>";
   echo "<div style ='font:21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#7a1ac4'><b>`Name of School:`</b> 
   $nos</div>";
   echo "<div style ='font:21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#7a1ac4'><b>`Gender:`</b> 
   $gender</div>";
   echo "<div style ='font:21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#7a1ac4'><b>`Level of Academics:`</b> 
   $loa</div>";
?>
```

Comment: "it isn't working", is a poor description of the problems you're experiencing. Do you get a blank page? errors? Is the result incorrect? If so, how? Etc. Can you give examples of wanted input and output?

Comment: Kindly add better title, and where your stuck now and add ecxpected input and output for this prbm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this for age calculation:

```php
$today = new DateTime("now");
$birthdate = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day");
$age = $today->diff($birthdate)->y;
```

**Update:** 
So the whole code with some cleanup will be like:

```php
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $day = $_POST['day'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $today = new DateTime("now");
    $birthdate = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day");
    $age = $today->diff($birthdate)->y;
    $nos = $_POST['nos'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $loa = $_POST['loa'];
?>
<div style ='font:21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#7a1ac4'>
    <b>`Name:`</b>
    <?php echo $name; ?>
</div>;
<div style ='font:21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#7a1ac4'>
    <b>`Birth Date:`</b>
    <?php echo $birthdate->format('Y-m-d'); ?>
</div>;
<div style ='font:21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#7a1ac4'>
    <b>`Age:`</b> aprox.
    <?php echo $age; ?>
</div>;
<div style ='font:21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#7a1ac4'>
    <b>`Name of School:`</b>
    <?php echo $nos; ?>
</div>;
<div style ='font:21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#7a1ac4'>
    <b>`Gender:`</b>
    <?php echo $gender; ?>
</div>;
<div style ='font:21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#7a1ac4'>
    <b>`Level of Academics:`</b>
    <?php echo $loa; ?>
</div>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, the `F` should be replaced by `n`:

F
A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March
January through December

n
Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros
1 through 12

```
   if (date('n') <= $month) {
        $age = date('Y') - $year;
   }
```